# Get value of current event handler using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can set the onclick handler using jQuery by calling

```
$('#id').click(function(){
   console.log('click!');
});
```

Also using jQuery, how can I get a reference to the function which is currently handling the click() event?

The reason is that I have another object and want to set its click handler to the same one as #id.

#### Update

Thank you for all the suggestions. The problem is that I do not know which function is currently handling the clicks. Keeping track of it would add state to an already complicated template-editing system.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. The problem is that I do not know which function is currently handling the clicks. Keeping track of it would add state to an already complicated template-editing system.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Comment: I have found a different way to solve my issue, eliminating the need for this. Thank you all for putting so much effort into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `.click(function)` method adds the function to a queue that is executed on the click event~

So actually pulling out a reference to the given function would probably be hairy-er than you expect.

As noted by others, it would be better to pass in a reference to the function; and then you already have the reference you need.

```
var clicky = function () { /* do stuff */ };
$('#id').click(clicky);
// Do other stuff with clicky
```

### Update

If you really really need to get it out, try this:

```
jQuery._data(document.getElementById('id')).events.click[0].handler
```

Depending on your version of jQuery that may or may not work~ Try playing around with

```
jQuery._data(document.getElementById('id'))
```

and see what you get.

Got the idea from this section of the source:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#LC36

Answer (score 0):

**if you dont know the name of the function you can use**

*args.callee*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

```
function clickHandle(e){
  if($(e.target) == $('#id')) {
  $(newTarget).bind('click',  clickHandle);
  }
}

$('#id').bind('click',clickHandle);
```

I think this would be the most symantic way of going about it