# with Jquery, how to get the function that the button binds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I have below codes written with jquery:

```
  <script>
 $(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () { alert("OK"); });
    });
 </script>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="input" id="btn1" /><label id="lbl"></label><br />
</body>
```

I need get the function of btn1. The pseudo code as follows:

```
var f=Get_function_of_btn1("#btn1").
```

Then, when I call f(), it alerts "OK".

How to implement it?

BTW, can jquery print the function as string? like below:

```
console.log(f);
```

then it will print :

```
function () { alert("OK"); }
```

Comment: why not just use $("#btn1").click() to trigger the function on command?

Comment: I know use $("#btn1").click() is OK, but I wonder is there another solution.

Comment: Looks like this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086106/get-value-of-current-event-handler-using-jquery

Comment: Here is the true duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583330/javascript-object-get-code-as-string   also see my comment to Rory M.'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function in the standard manner with an identifier:

```
function foo() {
    alert('OK');
}
```

You can then assign this function to the `click()` handler and retrieve it in a `console.log` (not that I see the point of the latter):

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(foo);
});

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: need to `.toString()` foo in the log for it to print the actual function.

Answer (score 1):

you could call the function from the button itself:

```
<input type="button" value="输入" id="btn1" onclick='f();' />
```

```js
function f(){
    alert("ok");
}
```

Comment: It's a jQuery question... Don't encourage the use of *attribute-based* event handlers like `onclick`! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign function to variables too:

```
var f = function(){
    alert('ok');
}
f();
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q48o4ajj/1/)**

For the console-ouput you can use:

```
console.log(f.toString());
```

Thanks @Buck3y3 for the hint